# Strong coupling in Cavity Optomechanics - Spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I am trying to get an intuitive understanding for some plots that I have made. I am studying the crossover between the weak -and strong coupling regime in Cavity Optomechanics. Recall that in Cavity Optomechanics we study the coupling between a mechanical resonator with frequency $\omega_m$ and dissipation rate $\gamma$ and a cavity with frequency $\omega_0$ and dissipation rate $\kappa$, i.e.
$$H_c = \hbar \omega_0 a^{\dagger}a, H_m = \hbar \omega_m b^{\dagger}b$$

In addition, we drive the cavity with a classical field such that $H_d = \hbar\epsilon(e^{i\omega_dt + e^{-i\omega_d t}})(a + a^{\dagger})$ and set a coupling strength $g_0$, giving the *effective* Hamiltonian

$$H = H_c + H_m + \hbar g_0a^{\dagger}a(b + b^{\dagger}) + H_d$$

Going to the rotating frame at $\omega_d$, applying the RWA and setting a detuning $\Delta = \omega_d - \omega_0$, we get the final Hamiltonian
$$H = -\hbar\Delta a^{\dagger}a + \hbar \omega_m b^{\dagger}b + \hbar\epsilon(a + a^{\dagger)} + \hbar g_0a^{\dagger}a(b + b^{\dagger})$$

From this, we get the Quantum Langevin equations of motion (including dissipation and neglecting quantum noise fluctuations) for operators $a$ and $b$;
$$\frac{d}{dt}a = i\Delta a - \frac{\kappa}{2}a - i\epsilon - ig_0(b + b^{\dagger})$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}b = -i\omega_m b - \frac{\gamma}{2} - i g_0|a|^2$$.

By setting the derivative to zero and taking the average (i.e. $\langle a \rangle = \alpha)$, I get a coupled system of equations that I can solve for $|\alpha|^2 = n_{Cavity}$ and $|\beta|^2 = n_{Mech. Oscillator}$.

Now, while I understand the math, I don't understand the physics behind this, in particular the crossover from the weak-coupling $g_0 \ll \omega_m$ to the strong-coupling $g_0 \ll \omega_m$ regime.

For example, for $g_0 = 0.05 * \omega_m$, I get the following plot for $n_{Cavity}$ and $n_{Mech. Oscillator}$ using the above Hamiltonian and QUTIP's steady-state solver.

```
# Define operators
a_c = tensor(destroy(N_c), qeye(N_m))
b_m = tensor(qeye(N_c), destroy(N_m))
n_c = a_c.dag() * a_c
n_m = b_m.dag() * b_m

# Loss rates
c_op_list = [np.sqrt(kappa) * a_c, np.sqrt(gamma) * b_m]

# Hamiltonian
def detuned_Hamiltonian_B(delta):
    H = - delta * n_c + w_m + n_m + g_0 * n_c * (b_m + b_m.dag()) + drive * (a_c + a_c.dag())
    return  H

# Getting the final steady state
H = detuned_Hamiltonian_B(delta)
final_state = steadystate(H, c_op_list)
```

Now, in the last part, I have to provide a **no-numbers** explanation for the following spectra:

I am aware how radiation pressure works, and I also now blue / red sidebands that correspond to a a photon entering the cavity, exciting a phonon in the mechanical oscillator and leaving the cavity with a lower frequency. However, I can't make the connection between that, the math, and the plot.
[image]

Why is there a shoulder for positive detuning? Why is there a frequency splitting for the mechanical oscillator?